# autofocus on input form

Tags: php, codeigniter, authentication, autofocus

i'm trying to set autofocus on my input form, i'm confused to apply existing example to my program.. please anybody help me. thanks.

```
    <body>
 <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="text"> 
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <?php 

    echo form_open('login/validateform');
        echo 'user name';
    echo form_input('username', '');
    echo 'password';
        echo form_password('password', '');

        echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');


 </div>
 </body>
```

Comment: you need to provide your elements with `id` attribute and a unique value to it. then from a jquery ready block you can say `$('#id').focus();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution on the manual:
`echo form_input($auto_focus);` where $auto_focus is (create it):

```
$auto_focus = array(
              'autofocus'   => 'autofocus',
            );

echo form_input($auto_focus);
```

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html search for (ctrl + f) *form_input()* on this page

Your code will be:

```
<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
     <div id="text"> 
       <h2>Login</h2>
        <?php 
            $auto_focus = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'autofocus'   => 'autofocus',
            );

        echo form_open('login/validateform');
            echo 'user name';
        echo form_input($auto_focus);
        echo 'password';
            echo form_password('password', '');

            echo form_submit('submit', 'Login');

           //dont forget to close php
         ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Before using php, and library, be sure to know how to write good html code... You made lot of mistakes.

Comment: thank you very much, it's run on my program.. sorry, i'm still a new programmer :)

Answer (score 2):

Not only for PHP but also for others web applications, we can set autofocus on input field by following HTML 5 and Javascript code

```
<input type='text' name='username' id='inputFieldId' autofocus="autofocus" />

<script>
    if (!("autofocus" in document.createElement("input")))
            document.getElementById("inputFieldId").focus();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use html5 autofocus it is supported now in all majore browsers.

```
 <input type='text' name='username' autofocus="true" />
```

Comment: This does not work in Firefox.  "autofocus" is not an attribute.

Answer (score 0):

echo form_input(array(
                        "name" => "username",
                        "id" => "email",
                        "class" => "form-control",
                        "maxlength" => "255",
                        "size" => "50",
                        "autofocus"   => "autofocus",
                    ));